# How many circles with radius $r_1$ can be inscribed in circle with radius $r_2$

Tags: geometry, circles

Is there formula for finding the number of inscribed circles in a bigger circle?

For example:
Little circles radius: $7 cm$;
Big circle radius: $50cm$;

Comment: You mean the maximum number of circles that can be inscribed together, I suppose. Difficult problem, see *[Circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing)* and *[Circle packing in a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle)* on Wikipedia.

Comment: Also, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html).

Comment: Is the number finite ?

Comment: @sammath If you are talking about the number that can be inscribed together while not overlap, it is of course finite. If there is not this condition, this is not... you can inscribe an infinite number of circles into a bigger one.

Comment: Without overlapping. Yes, I'm searching the maximum number. Seems that the wikipedia article is what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this:

[image: fig]

The big circle radius is $r_2=AB$ and the little circle radius $r_1=CB=CE$. Recognizing the right triangle $AEC$ you find the relationship

$$ \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} = \frac{CE}{AC} = \frac{r_1}{r_2-r_1} $$

once you have the angle $\alpha$ you  can calculate the number of circles that fit in $2\pi$ as $$N={\rm integer}(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha})$$

Comment: This will only give you how many circles you can insert along the boundary; you can inscribe more which are in contact with these. See Wikipedia's page on [circle packing in a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle) for images.

Comment: Yes, rinse and repeat the process to get to the next layer.

Comment: Eh, if it were that simple then I doubt there would be as many entries on that page marked as 'conjectured to be optimal'...

Comment: The OP never said optimal.

Comment: His last comment to the OP does.