# Prove that any circle of radius R can have exactly seven inscribed circles, each of radius R/3.

Tags: calculus, geometry

Any ideas on how to get started on this? I figure the inscribed circles are adjacent inside the original circle and the inscribed circles are tangent but I am stuck on how to prove this.

Comment: See last picture on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648882/six-circles-are-inscribed-in-a-big-circle-such-that-each-circle-touches-its-two

Comment: Similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942775/how-many-circles-with-radius-r-1-can-be-inscribed-in-circle-with-radius-r-2

Comment: Page 56 of this book provides a lengthy answer:https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=AzcDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA55&dq=INSCRIBE+small+CIRCLE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8uu_2jq_iAhWHzYUKHYf0DdwQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=INSCRIBE%20small%20CIRCLE&f=false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If inside a big circle , exactly n $(n \geq 3)$ small circles, each of radius r,can be drawn in such a way that each small circle touches t........](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510723/if-inside-a-big-circle-exactly-n-n-geq-3-small-circles-each-of-radius-r)

Answer (score 0):

Put the centre of the big circle at $0\in\mathbb{C}$.  Then the seven small circles with vertices $0, \frac23R\exp(k\pi i/3)$.  By a straightforward computation, these centres are $\geq\frac23R$ apart so the smaller circles do not overlap.  Triangle inequality gives, for $P$ on a small circle with centre $C$,
$$
\operatorname{dist}(P,0)=\lvert P-0\rvert\leq\lvert P-C\rvert+\lvert C-0\rvert\leq \frac13R+\frac23R=R
$$
so these seven small circles are inside in the big circle except for the six points where $0,C,P$ are collinear in that order and $C\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Draw an equilateral hexagon, side length $1$, with opposite vertices joined. Note that this splits the hexagon into six equilateral triangles, and so placing a circle at each point with radius $\frac{1}{2}$ creates seven tangent circles. Drawing a larger circle with radius $\frac{3}{2}$ with the same centre of the hexagon finishes the problem.